# How to inject play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple.Session inside a slick DAO component

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, slick, play-slick

I'm using the cake pattern for injecting dependencies between components in a play 2.2.1 application. Application is composed of play controllers and we use a custom `ActionBuilder` to open our DB session. We currently pass that DB session all the way back to our model layer through the controller and DAO layers as implicit argument. (ActionBuilder -> Controller -> DAO -> Slick Model)

I use play-slick for slick integration and try to use a DAO approach to encapsulate access to our slick models. Our DAOs have several function definitions like `findById(id: Int)(implicit s: Session): Option[Entity]`. I would like to avoid that implicit session parameter in every single function definition by injecting a DBSession-retrieving component. This component would be invoked inside the DAO function blocks everytime to retrieve the current request db session.

Coming from the Java and Spring world, I don't know exactly how to achieve that given that I probably can't rely on any ThreadLocal scoped proxy.

Any idea how I would be able to achieve that? 
Is this a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of your methods into a class, that takes an implicit session as an argument and then you always first instantiate the class and then call a method. Example here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/connection.html#passing-sessions-around

Comment: It's not the most elegant IMO, but I guess it's my last resort unless we can rely on some sort of short-term storage for the db session.

Comment: You use the class to basically implement partial application for a bunch of methods at the same time. There is also dynamicSession, which is "some sort of short-term storage for the db session", but it is far less elegant and generally advised against. Elegance comes not necessarily from the beauty of the syntax, but from the robustness and easy of use of the concept.

Comment: The Action monad coming up in Slick 2.2 may be a more elegant solution, allowing to compose not only queries, but a mix of queries and ordinary Scala code without ever exposing the Session explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can retrieve the DB Session as a function of the Request, then you could provide an implicit conversion to convert Request => DBSession.

Like this:

```
implicit def request2DBSession(request: Request[T]): DBSession = ???
```

Inside of which you can perform your DBSession retrieval.

EDIT:

Better yet you could use action composition to inject a Session with each request:

```
trait BaseController extends Controller {
  def DBAction(f: (request[_]) => DBSession => Result) = {
    Action { request =>
      val dbSession = ??? // Lookup DBSession
      f(request)(dbSession)
    }
  }  
}

object Controller extends BaseController {
  def lookupUser = DBAction { implicit request => implicit dbSession =>
    ??? // DBSession in Implicit Scope (free to use slick calls)
  }
}
```

This would be a little cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: My question is how can we avoid to do that! I want to mix-in a SessionLocator component to my DAO components that will be able to give that session to me. Otherwise I have to declare that parameter everywhere on my DAO traits!

Comment: Ah sorry! Looks like I misunderstood your question. You could potentially wrap the Session inside of a Dao object and instantiate it inside of the Action. The action builder could then pass the dao to the embedded function instead of the session. This way controller code would never need to see a Session. You could also do this by introducing a dao retrieving component instead of the session retrieving component you were thinking of. Apart from something like that, any solution I can think of would be worse than the original problem using implicits.